# map with multiple parameters

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, higher-order-functions

The type of map is:

```
:t map
(a -> b) -> [a] -> [b]
```

So if I would like to map a function with multiple parameters onto an array, something like:

```
myObviouslyFakeFunction :: Int -> Char -> String -> Char -> Integer -> String
myObviouslyFakeFunction -pattern- = -Very complex transform-
```

and do something like:

```
map (myObviouslyFakeFunction 1 'a' "abc" 'b' 2) ["abc", "def", "ghi"]
```

How could I do this? Would `a` in the type signature represent the first parameter? A tuple with all of them? A list?

Comment: `(myObviouslyFakeFunction 1 'a' "abc" 'b' 2)` is a `String`, not a function.

Comment: any chance you could clarify? I feel like I'm missing something incredibly basic... Why isn't it a function? Doesn't the above define it as a function (that returns a string?) To paraphrase a language I am more familiar with is that not equivalent to 
public string myObviouslyFakeFunction(int i, char c, string s, char c2, int i2){}?
How does it differ?

Comment: @AbrahamP - Its a string because you've provided all the arguments to `myObvisoulyFakeFunction`. You could partially apply a function `a1 -> a2 .. -> aN -> String -> b` to create a function `String -> b` and pass that to map, but `myObviouslyFakeFunction` does not follow that pattern.

Comment: Let's say you've got a function `f :: Int -> Int`. Then `f 1` is an `Int`.

Comment: @AbrahamP In Java (or whatever that is) it would be equivalent to `myObviouslyFakeFunction(1, 'a', "abc", 'b', 2)` which would be a string, not a function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to use `myObviouslyFakeFunction` like

```
map (myObviouslyFakeFunction 1 'a' "abc" 'b' 2) ["abc", "def", "ghi"]
```

then the type of it should be

```
myObviouslyFakeFunction :: Int -> Char -> String -> Char -> Integer -> String -> ResultType
```

Because `map` needs a one-parameter function, in this case with type `String -> b` (`b` is a type variable, could be any valid type), as its first argument, and if `myObviouslyFakeFunction` has the above type,

```
(myObviouslyFakeFunction 1 'a' "abc" 'b' 2)
```

will be a `String -> ResultType` function.

Answer (score 2):

I think, if i got you right, what you want to do is just

map (\x->myObviouslyFakeFunction 1 'a' x 'b' 2) ["abc", "def", "ghi"]

Answer (score 1):

This might clarify a little bit:

```
myObviouslyFakeFunction :: Int -> Char -> String -> Char -> Integer -> String 
myObviouslyFakeFunction 1 :: Char -> String -> Char -> Integer -> String 
myObviouslyFakeFunction 1 'a' :: String -> Char -> Integer -> String 
myObviouslyFakeFunction 1 'a' "abc" :: Char -> Integer -> String 
myObviouslyFakeFunction 1 'a' "abc" 'b' :: Integer -> String
myObviouslyFakeFunction 1 'a' "abc" 'b' 2 :: String
```

What you want to give to `map` is something of type `a -> b`, but this is of type `String`. If you had redefined your function so that it would have the following type (for some type `b`)

```
myObviouslyFakeFunction' :: Int -> Char -> String -> Char -> Integer -> String -> b
```

then we would have that

```
myObviouslyFakeFunction' 1 'a' "abc" 'b' 2 :: String -> b
```

Then you can apply it to the list of `String`s.